# Replace string - How to replace each word once

Tags: javascript, string

I have an xml dictionary as shown below.

```
<word definition="The primary income-earner in a household">bread winner</word>
<word definition="One who wins, or gains by success in competition, contest, or gaming">winner</word>
```

Whenerver there is a word from dictionary in my html, that word will be replaced with link and definition as title. When link is hovered, user should see the definition.

```
var allwords = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("word");
for (var i=0; i<allwords.length; i++)
    {
            var name = allwords[i].lastChild.nodeValue;

            var linked = '<a href ="#" title="' +  allwords[i].lastChild.nodeValue + ': ' + allwords[i].getAttribute("definition") + '">' + allwords[i].lastChild.nodeValue + '</a>'; 
    }
```

Here is my replacer

```
function replacer(oldstring, newstring) {
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(oldstring, newstring);
}
```

But problem is 
once **bread winner** changes to linked form, also **winner** changes since **bread winner** includes **winner**, winner changes twice, and all the code mixes up.

I am asking if there is a way, once **bread winner** changes **winner** should not change anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<allwords.length; i++)
{
    if(allwords[i].firstChild.name == 'a') {
        // This word has been linked already, skip it
    }

    // your code
}
```

Comment: this is a better solution than mine - same idea, but much more efficient implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of sentry to prevent processing a term that's already been processed. I'd recommend wrapping the replaced terms with another element (not clear on how your html is structured, so I'm not sure what would work here, but a span would be the simplest way in normal html). Then your logic would just skip replacing words that had a parent element of whatever you decided to wrap it with.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate through the matching text nodes, and only replace those that don't have an A tag as an ancestor in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Try function [strtr](http://php.net/strtr)($text, $fromList, $toList). It should replace each term once.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. One, it's PHP and two, it would be extremely impractical to use a hypothetical JS `strtr` because the point is that the values you want to search/replace are not known at compile time.

Comment: Don't know why I thought it is a PHP question. No problem though – use ported JavaScript strtr function [http://phpjs.org/functions/strtr:556](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtr:556).